# How to put border around set of table rows in Android?

Tags: android, border, android-tablelayout

I have read similar questions here, but none of them cleared my doubt.

I have read about adding border to each cell, table row, etc. But I need to have a border (kind of a box)  around some set of rows.

Lets assume that a table has 5 rows, but i want to enclose 3 rows in a separate box and the other 2 rows in a separate box.

I want to do it programmatically from java code behind; is it possible? 
[image]

The rectangles having sphere in it are the elements of tablerow and i have set a green and red background to some set of tablerows. I want it to be shown just like border, like a box containing the set of rows instead of a complete red and green background. I hope I am  clear with my question. Need your suggestions..

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by set `background` and `padding` for your rows.of course I think still other ways exist.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:text=" blue border "
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:text="red border"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:text="green border"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

[image]

UPDATE:

in your activity you can change border color by `TabaleRow` id:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TableRow row1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    row1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    TableRow row2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.t2);
    row2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    TableRow row3 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.t3);
    row3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

}
```

Comment: This again is a border around each table row. I want it around set of rows. Also, can you provide ways to do it programmatically from java?

Comment: you can set "id" for each "TableRow" and in your activity setBackgrounColor for each one. like this : tableRow1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

Comment: can you please explain a bit? Also, my row contains buttons with drawableTop images, so applying color would be minimal. Can you provide a more concrete suggestion?

Comment: I edit answer see above. also put your TableRows here to show you how do it in yours

Comment: please see my updated question. As per your suggestion, i have set the background color, but it looks like this. I have explained in the question what I need to develop.

Comment: just set a parent for your sphere like "LinearLayout" with background="#fff" and set padding for your tableRow as I mentioned above.in short answer , put your sphere in Linear or relative layout and set background color for your linear/relative layout(note According to your image you should set color to white)